# How to deal with overflows while using either Welford's or Youngs-Cramer algorithms for variance?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, variance

I'm trying to use either of the mentioned algorithms to calculate sample variance. However I ran into this problem -- Welford's algorithm uses for accumulations a sum of differences  of elements and accumulated mean. If the mean is close to 0, this basically turns into sum of squares of elements -- which leads to overflows if the elements and the number of them are big. Is there a way around that?

Comment: For those like me who don't know Welford algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance

Comment: Are you using an integer number type? In that case you may consider using doubles

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already trying to implement it for doubles.

Comment: Because Welford's method uses a *running* mean, I think you can partially mitigate this by reordering the data so that the next term you're adding is close to the current mean. Catastrophic cancellation is potentially a concern though. If you just want to throw more bits at the problem, `long double` is 80 bits in some environments. A decimal library is another option, but will be slow. You might get more visibility on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don‘t understand your problem. Most of the time this method will add squares,Even of the meaning is  not near 0. Can you describe you describe your problem and your dataset more precisely.

Comment: @ZachB Sorting the data does Not make Sense. You use this algorithm to avoid reading the data more than once. If you dort you read it about $n\log n$ times. Beeidest that it won‘t solve a Problem. Also there is Not catastrophic cancellation if you add positive Numbers as the OP describes. Finallly i think that computerscience is Not an appropriate stackexchange. The Problem is appropriate for math stackexchange Here. But there is also scientific Computing where one Could post it. Actually I think the Op‘s Problem is Rather simple to solve

Comment: @miracle173 Welford's method is not just used because it's single-pass. It's also used because it's less (or not at all) susceptible to loss of significance when working with floating-point numbers. Catastrophic cancellation *is* a consideration when subtracting the mean. If it's simple to solve, what's your suggestion?

Comment: I have come to a conclusion that for sufficiently big numbers overflow is unavoidable if we are using rationals. So I resorted to using long doubles. That loses me some precision but oh well.

Comment: @AndrewS. the Right conclusion. But Why did you Even try rationals?

Comment: @ZachB Of course one would not use a method that is susceptible to loss of significance. But I think Welford's method has no better numerical properties than the [two pass algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). The OP said he has an overflow problem when adding the squares, which are positive numbers, and I said there is no cancellation problem when one adds positive numbers. There is nothing wrong with my statement. The solution of the OP's problem was already suggested by the OP himself. He has to use floating point numbers instead of fractions

Comment: @miracle173 in the third comment they said they were already using doubles. - The addition is fine, but this algorithm also subtracts the mean at each step. That is prone to cancellation.

Comment: @AndrewS. Check out pages 11-16 of https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03482567, which reviews a cheap, adaptive scaling method using scalbn. If your chief concern is overflow and you use that, you might not even need Welford's or Y-C's methods.